# Change excel cell number format "General" to "Text", using openpyxl 1.8.6

Tags: openpyxl

How to change excel cell number format `General` to `Text` irrespective of data in cell?

I am using openpyxl 1.8.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number formatting applies only to numbers. If you want to change a number to text then you must change the datatype:

`ws['A1'] = str(ws['A1'].value)`

Version 1.8.6 is no longer supported. You should consider upgrading to a more recent release.

Answer (score 26):

I know this question is really old, but it could still be relevant as I just found it when Googling the same thing. The above will work most of the time, but not in those annoying cases where Excel starts acting like guys I've known in the past, and thinking everything is a date. ;)

I would do it like this:

```
cell = ws['A1']
cell.number_format = '@'
```

The `'@'` is a placeholder that forces text formatting. The docs suggest this works on version 1.8.6, as well as latest release.

Comment: That pun at the end of first paragraph is one of the funniest things I've read on SO. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Based on @SuperScienceGrl's great answer:

```py
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
```

You can see a full list of format at their [official readthedocs page](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html)

Answer (score 4):

Applying @run_the_race answer to a column:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

xlsx_file = 'file.xlsx'

# openning:
wb = load_workbook(filename = xlsx_file)

# set column O of default sheet to be text:
ws = wb.active
for row in ws[2:ws.max_row]:  # skip the header
    cell = row[14]            # column O
    cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT

# saving:
wb.save(xlsx_file)
```

Same wrapped in a script accepting a column "name", like `AA`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import numbers


# ==============
## parsing args:

desc="""
Converts given column of the xlsx file (default sheet) to a text format.

Dependencies:
pip3 install --user --upgrade openpyxl
"""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.01')

parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                    help = "xlsx file",
                    dest = 'xlsx_file',
                    type = argparse.FileType('r'),
                    )

parser.add_argument('-c', '--column',
                    help = "column (default to %(default)s)",
                    dest = 'column',
                    type = str,
                    default = "A",
                    )

args = parser.parse_args()


# =========
## program:

xlsx_file = args.xlsx_file.name

column_number = sum(
    [ ord(char) - 97 + i*26 for i,char in enumerate(
        list( args.column.lower() )
        ) ]
)

# openning:
wb = load_workbook(filename = xlsx_file)

# convert given column of the default sheet to a text format:
ws = wb.active
for row in ws[2:ws.max_row]:        # skip the header
    cell = row[column_number]
    cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT

# saving:
wb.save(xlsx_file)
```