# How can I make every cell in an excel template be of text format with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, format, cell, openpyxl

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833900/change-excel-cell-number-format-general-to-text-using-openpyxl-1-8-6) it is answered how to change a single cell to text format. In a nutshell, I can do

```
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
```

Using for loops I can extend this to multiple cells.

But how can I make *all* cells adapt text-format? E.g. if somebody later manually puts a date like `2022-04-27` into cell `CD130000`, how can I ensure that the format will be of text and the date won't get auto-changed by excel?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot select the whole sheet and set all cells to text with openpyxl. See **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024597/openpyxl-set-number-format-for-the-whole-column** for similar query. If a user manually enters data they can set all cells to text...

Comment: But it is possible in the front end of excel via hitting `Ctrl + A` and then selecting text format. So maybe there is some API way to do so, too?

Comment: You need to set the format for all relevant cells. If necessary, this means creating cells. Excel should then respect that format unless Excel's heuristics detect a date or time or other special format.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Xlwings

```
import xlwings as xw


wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')
### Either of the following two lines should set the whole sheet to 'Text'
ws.api.Cells.NumberFormat = '@'
ws.cells.number_format = '@'
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, thank you! :)